# Poorly Painted Rebus (1)

Tags: rebus

[image]

What might we say about this person?
<sub>The answer to this riddle is a common object, phrase, or idiom</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Second attempt**

Perhaps we can say that this person

> Knows the ropes

Because

> They appear to be thinking about piles of rope.

**Original incorrect guess**

I think that this person is

> Forward Thinking

Reasoning

> The things in the thought bubble look like stone [wards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey_(castle)), so perhaps the person is "four ward thinking" which sounds like "forward thinking".

Comment: Sorry, what kind of 'ward' do these resemble? I'm struggling to make out what they are! (Probably my eyes' fault...) EDIT: Just seen you edited in a link.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not seeing any 'wards' either :(

Comment: Ah, okay, it was a bit of a stretch.

Comment: +1 because your second guess beat me to it. Could also be "I should think not" ("think knot"). It doesn't help that I can't tell if those are coiled ropes, woolen hats, or piles o' whatzit.

Comment: Well done, that's it!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this person

> Has "multiple thoughts" because they think in multi-piles? Probably also a bit of a stretch.

Comment: That's knot it, sorry.