# A Range of Rebuses

Tags: rebus, metapuzzles

In the Land of Rebuses, I found some paper, as well as a few images:

> [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Some of these have already been tackled here: [1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94262/poorly-painted-rebus-1) [2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94266/poorly-painted-rebus-2) [3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94272/poorly-painted-rebus-3) [4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94277/poorly-painted-rebus-4)
<sub>Any images were found on [freesvg.org](https://freesvg.org) or drawn manually. The answers to the rebuses are common words, phrases, or idioms</sub>

Hint 1:

> 3 idioms, 2 creatures, and 1 superlative for the first 6

Comment: If you saw my last comment, I deleted because I noticed they're all pictures (so easy to differentiate each rebus) - but now I'm a little lost again. 7 images but 6 mentioned in post? Is the final image == the last clue and is also a rebus besides being ascertained from the other 6? or..?

Comment: The final image is a place and a clue at the same time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key to end the game is to

> King Me

Four rebuses were already solved

> Know the ropes
>  Hit below the belt
>  Sunfish
>  All Greek to Me

The fifth rebus is

> Chipmunk = (Chips x 1) + Monk

The sixth rebus is

> Severest = S + Everest

The seventh rebus is

> Diagonally = Die-A-gon + Ally (The flag is the "Straight Ally" flag)

Finally

> The seventh clue is used to get the answer. To me, it indicates putting the previous six answers together and reading diagonally as follows
>
> ```
>  
>  KNOWTHEROPES
>  HITBELOWTHEBELT
>  SUNFISH
>  ALLGREEKTOME
>  CHIPMUNK
>  SEVEREST
> ```
>
> Thus we get **KINGME** or with appropriate spacing **KING ME**.

Comment: That's checker-mate, well done!